# Asking for a comparison of two options

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

**Is it allowed, and if so, *how* do I word a question, which requests an answer based on the benefits of using something over the other?**

For example, is the following question valid?:

> Are there any benefits of using Java over C++ for ___?
>   I completely understand that C++ does ___, ___ and ___ better than Java, but is there any benefit of using Java that outweighs that of what C++ can do?

I'm thinking of asking this very question, but would like to know if its valid beforehand. I would be asking a question that could *potentially* be "opinionated" in a sense that I'm not actually asking for a direct answer to a problem but almost in a way a "discussion"; but then on top of that it's not asking for an opinion, its looking for a direct, logical benefit to support one over the other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: @RobertLongson However if you look at the Gorilla vs Shark question, it specifically revolves around the question: "What should I use? Gorilla or Shark?" What I'm asking, is ***why*** should I use Shark, instead of Gorilla. I provide reasons for Gorilla, I request people provide reasons for Shark.

Comment: You're still not likely to get anywhere here. We don't do discussions.

Comment: @RobertLongson Exactly right. But somehow I just can't pinpoint the right word to use for the question. I personally don't believe its a discussion at all. Each to their own I guess. Lets see what others think. Hmm...

Comment: @frayment - *Robert is right*. In whichever way you frame your question of X vs Y, there will always be a discussion and you will end up with *opinions*, not concrete answers

Comment: The basic answer to this question is that you should use the programming language that you know best. If you know both equally well, pick whichever one you want—it really doesn't matter. There. Now you won't ever have to wonder or ask again.

Comment: @CodyGray Well when I'm working on a compiler, I want Java's features but C++'s speed and low-level features. For the question I'm thinking of asking, it's not as black and white as you think.

Comment: There is nothing in Java that does not already exist in or cannot be trivially added to C++ with a library, so your statement does not make sense. For example, you can add garbage collection to C++ (of course, by doing so, you sacrifice "speed and low-level", which means you might as well have just written it in Java, except if you're a C++ programmer like me and don't know Java, then you should write it in C++).

Comment: @frayment Basically, if you're a Java dev, you'll code X quicker in Java than C++, and the same is true in the opposite way. When the answer have to take into account coder's ability/actual knowledge, it's open ended and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If anything, you would have to have an ***extremely laser focused*** question about an extremely specific aspect. If your *"for ___"* is something general like "for web scraping", you have a gorilla-shark question. If it's something super specific like "executing this particular integer addition millions of times", presumably you could benchmark a prototype and find your own answer that way. Somewhere in-between these two *may* be a question specific yet not obvious enough to be worth asking; but that's a very small window.

Comment: Its been a long time ago I did something "just" with Java or C++. I generally need a gigantic pile of tooling on top of the platform to in a reasonable time frame deliver a working solution. The platform/language itself is pretty irrelevant actually, its the landscape that has been shaped using it VS the requirements of whatever is to be implemented that form the deal breaker. As such I would deem the question far too broad.

Comment: Whether or not a question like that is answerable totally depends on the context. Java obviously wins on land, while C++ has a clear advantage in water. But in a more neutral setting, e.g. outer space, the answer inherently becomes much more subjective.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I like your wording of the context. The question is, how subjective can we go on SE?

Comment: @deceze My only issue is, for what I want to do, make a toy-compiler or something along the lines, I can't just simply benchmark.

Comment: These are all great comments, so thankyou all. Some of you should turn them into answers!

Comment: While there isn't really an _exact_ answer for that, basically as close to "not subjective at all" as possible. We want questions that can be answered, and opinions and discussions aren't answers. The "primarily opinion-based" close reason exists for a good reason. And I don't want to make my stupid comment into an answer. It would probably be downvoted by people who think Java should get to be the shark.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Haha. I understand the Meta community can be quite savage in their voting as from what I have seen, but the context you place it in makes a lot of sense. Besides, better to think openly then press yourself into the Java corner.

Comment: There is nothing savage about providing information. Its actually remarkably eloquent to do your voting duties.

Comment: @Gimby Of course! However I do see some random downvotes or rather "mass" downvotes on a single question with no comments. One person can't perform 20 downvotes, and the information already comes across by the 3rd downvote.

Comment: But "Three people disagree with this" isn't the same information as "twenty people disagree with this." And votes already have a built-in meaning without comments.